# Using MozyPro, how can I back up files that are in use constantly?

Tags: backup, mozy

Our backups are failing because we're trying to back up a Windows service that is running - is there any way to run the backup without simultaneously disabling the Windows service?

Comment: In what way are the backups failing? To my knowledge Mozy knows how to use the Volume Shadow Copy service which is the solution for backing up open files, though for best results the application should be VSS aware.

Comment: Every time the backup runs, I get a "SnapshotError0", but the "Other Details" column on the backup history screen shows no errors.

Comment: What's being logged in the Windows System and Application event logs?

Comment: I did see an error saying that the shadow copy sections of two hard drives are full; I'd have to log in to the server again to see the exact message but I think that might be it...

Answer (score 1):

MozyPro uses the Microsoft Volume Shadow Copy Service to back up files even while they're in use. If you're having problems backing up open applications, something is wrong with VSS.

You can troubleshoot this by reviewing events in the System and Application event logs from the source `Volsnap`.

Be aware that in order to get data-consistent backups of application data the application itself must be VSS-aware. This is not something within Mozy's control. If the application is not VSS aware, Mozy will still be able to back its data up, but it will be in a crash-consistent state, i.e. the data will be in the same state it would be if the power was pulled from the machine immediately before the backup was taken.